# Highstock : Previous data still displayed when changing datagrouping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Sorry for the english ...

I got a chart with custom data grouping.
When I click to change the zoom, the new data are displayed **over** the previous one (which aren't deleted) :-(

```
rangeSelector : {
    allButtonsEnabled: true,
        buttons: [{
        type: 'month',
        count: 3,
        text: 'Day',
        dataGrouping: {
            forced: true,
            units: [['day', [1]]]
        }
    }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'Month',
        dataGrouping: {
            forced: true,
            units: [['month', [1]]]
        }
    }],
        selected: 2
},
```

I found a fiddle with this problem : 
http://jsfiddle.net/tqyyqmzs/12/

Month data are displayed.
Click on "Day" or "week" and you will see that month data sill be on the graph :-(

P.S : One or two month ago, this code works.
And now .... don't and I really don't understand why.

Did someone see the problem ?

Regards
David

---

Got the same problem on my website : 
https://www.bdpv.fr/en/ficheUtilisateur.php?util=boyardgo
Click on panel "Production"
Then click on zoom "Mois".
Same behaviour, data for mois stay ...

Comment: It works fine in 6.0.3 http://jsfiddle.net/tqyyqmzs/13/

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I add put https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/6.0.3/highstock.js in my code, instead of https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/highstock.js as a workaround and it's works !