# Highcharts Chart Corrupted on Range Selector Button Press

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It appears that when changing the data grouping via the range selector buttons, the chart does not erase the old dataGroupings, so the chart becomes messy quickly.  You can see the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/datagrouping/).

Is there any way to fix this?

Below is the code that generates the chart.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    chart: {
        height: 300
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        allButtonsEnabled: true,
        buttons: [{
            type: 'month',
            count: 3,
            text: 'Day',
            dataGrouping: {
                forced: true,
                units: [['day', [1]]]
            }
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: 'Week',
            dataGrouping: {
                forced: true,
                units: [['week', [1]]]
            }
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'Month',
            dataGrouping: {
                forced: true,
                units: [['month', [1]]]
            }
        }],
        buttonTheme: {
            width: 60
        },
        selected: 2
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Custom data grouping tied to range selector'
    },

    _navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: data,
        marker: {
            enabled: null, // auto
            radius: 3,
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: updated with the code, although the effect is not seen unless you visit the fiddle

Comment: It's a bug in 6.0.4 https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7547

Comment: Duplicate [Highstock : Previous data still displayed when changing datagrouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856293/highstock-previous-data-still-displayed-when-changing-datagrouping)