# Highstock dataGrouping issue: overlapping series

Tags: highcharts

Recently I found my pages with Highstock breaks. When clicking the range selector button, which I had defined the dataGrouping function, the series before grouping is still shown in the chart.

[img: the overlapping series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZXrP.png)

so I went back to find the [API reference](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons). It turned out that the example given in the API doc has the same issue with mine:

[the jsfiddle of the official example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/datagrouping/)

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        chart: {
            height: 300
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: 'Day',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['day', [1]]]
                }
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: 'Week',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['week', [1]]]
                }
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'Month',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['month', [1]]]
                }
            }],
            buttonTheme: {
                width: 60
            },
            selected: 2
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Custom data grouping tied to range selector'
        },

        _navigator: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: data,
            marker: {
                enabled: null, // auto
                radius: 3,
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

So I'm wondering if it's a bug with the new updated highstock.js code.

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273486/highcharts-chart-corrupted-on-range-selector-button-press) comments its a bug in 6.0.4

Comment: Thank you! sorry I didn't find out that there are replicate questions already.